# How to create a drag and drop using jquery html with clone of the dragged object and store its location on client side in the droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a keyboard in hmtl where the key characters (clone) have to be draggable and dropped onto a specific area only and then store its location details on client side so that the next time he comes back the last state is rendered.

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am Not sure what you are looking for but since you have mentioned drag and drop i would suggest using [kienticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) there are many tutorials which you can follow e.g check [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-the-stage-with-kineticjs/).Hope that will help.

Comment: Hi Aameer, 

Thanks for you reply,

Basically, I want to replicate the keyboard using html javascript. Instead of the typing interface I want the user to drag the alphabet ( dom element) and place it in a certain container and be able to drag it and place anywhere within that container. So the dragged item will have to be duplicated on drag. The data of the msg created in the container should be preserved so that its rendered back when the user return next time.

Thanks

Comment: for dragging and copying you can check the following eample http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop   from w3schools.Hope that will help.

Comment: Just instead of replacing the object make a copy of it